# Transform JSON rows into PostgreSQL Table

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a table in my database that returns me some columns. One of them is a list of JSONs that are, in fact, other tables, but in JSON format. The image belows show an example.

[image: Example of database in pgAdmin]

I want to transform each row of that column "data" into separate tables, because I need specific information inside each JSON. How can I do that using only PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below query to create transfer your data (json data column) into a new table

```
insert into json_table
SELECT p.*
from test_json t
cross join lateral json_populate_record (NULL::json_table, t.data ::json) as p;
```

Here **json_table** is the new table in which data will be stored, **test_json** is your table in which json data is stored in **data** column.
Replace those with your table names and you are good to go.

Comment: I run that code and it fills the json_table with same number of rows that I have on my original table, but the filled data in json_table is all null. What could solve that?

Comment: Would you please send some sample data from your table at kmnur@hotmail.com. So that I can check it for myself.

Comment: @LeoOmni Please check the column names of the table. Those should be same as the column names of json oibject. Otherwise this will insert null since no value is available against those column names in json object.

Comment: @LeoOmni please let me know whether your problem has been resolved or not.

Comment: I could soulve the problem successfully. Now I transformed my JSON rows into another table in my database and, despite some duplicate rows (wich can be solved with a simple SQL query) the table is just what I need.

Comment: That's great to know. Best wishes.